# Convert contents from a list tp dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list which looks something like this,

```
list = ['some random sentence','some random sentence 25% •Assignments for week1',
        'some random sentence','some random sentence 20% •Exam for week2','some random sentence',
        'some random sentence']
```

This is extracted from a pdf. I want to take only specific characters and words from a specific value in this list and convert it into pandas dataframe, something like this,

[image]

The word 'Assignment' is just an example, there could be different words but always after the percentage sign. It may have multiple spaces or sometimes 1-2 special characters.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There might be a way to do that, but it would require more information about the data. Also, what did you try to solve your problem? By the way, using `list` or any other builtin class or function as variable name is never a good idea, and neither is posting images of code, including expected outputs.

Comment: Still learning. What would be the ideal way then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `str.extract`:

```
l = ['some random sentence','some random sentence 25% •Assignments for week1',
        'some random sentence','some random sentence 20% •Exam for week2','some random sentence',
        'some random sentence']


out = (pd.Series(l)
         .str.extract(r'(?P<Weight>\d+%)\W*(?P<Object>\w+)')
         .dropna(subset='Object')
       )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
  Weight       Object
1    25%  Assignments
3    20%         Exam
```

##### older answer

If you have a single term to match:

```
l = ['some random sentence','some random sentence 25% •Assignments for week1',
        'some random sentence','some random sentence 20% •Assignments for week2','some random sentence',
        'some random sentence']

s = pd.Series(l)
m = s.str.contains('assignment', case=False)

out = (s[m].str.extract(r'(?P<Weight>\d+%)')
       .assign(Object='Assignment')
       )

print(out)
```

Alternative with a regex to match any number of terms:

```
s = pd.Series(l)
out = (s.str.extractall(r'(?P<Object>Assignment|otherword)|(?P<Weight>\d+%)')
       .groupby(level=0).first()
       )
```

Output:

```
       Object Weight
1  Assignment    25%
3  Assignment    20%
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple is using regex :

```
import re

def regex_split(sentence):
    match = re.search(r".+ (\d+)% •(\w+) for week\d", sentence)
    if match:
        return match.group(1) + '%', match.group(2)
    else:
        return "None"

df = pd.DataFrame({"sentence": list})
df["data"] = df["sentence"].apply(lambda x: regex_split(x))
df = df[df["data"] != "None"]
df["Object"] = df["data"].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df["Weight"] = df["data"].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df.drop(["sentence", "data"], axis=1)
```